# R Determine if a value ends in 0

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- tibble(
  col1 = c(10,12,8,20),
  col2 = c(45, 18, 10, 500))
```

I would like to pass a function over the data that determines if each value has 0 at the end. If it does the value is redefined as 'Pass', and if not it is defined as 'Fail'.

So the above data would look like this:

```
df2 <- tibble(
  col1 = c("Pass","Fail","Fail","Pass"),
  col2 = c("Fail", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass"))
```

Does anyone know how I would go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
df1 %% 10 == 0

      col1  col2
[1,]  TRUE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE
[4,]  TRUE  TRUE
```

The same with `dplyr`:

```
df1 %>%
 mutate_all(~ . %% 10 == 0)
```

Or with Pass/Fail:

```
df1 %>%
 mutate_all(~ if_else(. %% 10 == 0, "Pass", "Fail"))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ifelse(df1 %% 10 == 0, 'Pass', 'Fail')
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex approach could be to find out strings that end with 0 and assign values accordingly.

```
df1[] <- c("Fail", "Pass")[grepl("0$", unlist(df1)) + 1]
df1

# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  col1  col2 
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 Pass  Fail 
#2 Fail  Fail 
#3 Fail  Pass 
#4 Pass  Pass
```

Or similarly with `endsWith` without regex

```
df1[] <- c("Fail", "Pass")[endsWith(as.character(unlist(df1)), "0") + 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

An option using `substr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate_all(~ case_when(substring(., nchar(.)) == '0' ~ "Pass", TRUE ~ "Fail"))
```